# Is it possible get all districts of city using HERE API

Tags: javascript, geocoding, here-api

Hello if I have a city (or bbox) can I retrieve all its districts?

For example if I have `new york` I want to send a REST request and to get:

```json
{
"discrict" :[
     {
       "name": "two briges",
       "geojson" : "geojson code" // all bounding box is perfect
     },
     {
       "name": "seaport",
       "geojson" : "geojson code" // all bounding box is perfect
     }
]
}
```

or something similar

Comment: No, AFAIK there's no such API. Nonetheless, check the Advanced Datasets API, maybe you can use it to get districts within a bbox: https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-search-bbox.html

Comment: how can i reproduce something like this https://gruppoedoardo.serviziostime.it/? I've been searching for 8 hours and haven't found anything. I want just the list of all districts

Comment: For your use case I believe you don't need a REST API, you just need to find all Italian districts and store them on your server. So, I don't think HERE is the most suitable source for that. Have you checked if OpenStreetMap has the Italian districts mapped?

Comment: Yes, I checked and they are not standard therefore unusable. If I find the neighborhoods how can I use them on the map? (I know it's a great question, I just need a starting point). I searched openstreetmap, place API, nomination, compasses API but still haven't found a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the module HERE Geocoding & Search API v7 to accomplish the your solution.(You can check the response in the address)
Please go through following documentation for more information.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-examples.html